# Mongodb find() query : return only unique document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have document Like this

```
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork1",
    "pointID": "point001",
    "param": "param1",
    "resId": "123"
}
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork2",
    "pointID": "point002",
    "param": "param2",
    "resId": "246"
}
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork1",
    "pointID": "point003",
    "param": "param3"
    "resId": "123"
}
...
```

Is it possible  to get below response without using aggregate base on **resId** . I need without aggregate because i create golable pagination using find() and regex.

```
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork1",
    "pointID": "point001",
    "param": "param1",
    "resId": "123"
}
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork2",
    "pointID": "point002",
    "param": "param2",
    "resId": "246"
}
...
```

Comment: Without aggregation query, you need to perform filtering/grouping in your end. Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: You can achieve pagination with aggregate. Don't really understand why you wouldn't use it.